# Filter a list of lottery results for those matching at least 4 numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a list of 3,000 winning lottery numbers. Each winning lottery number is on its own row and is comprised of 6 individual numbers, each in their own column. The winning number's draw date is also included.

**Example:**
[image]

I have 6 cells in which to enter lookup numbers. I would like to return all winning lottery numbers that match at least 4 of the lookup numbers.

For example, if my lookup numbers were `7, 15, 23, 45, 56, 59` then a list containing all winning lottery numbers that matched at least 4 of those numbers would be returned.

I have the following formula working so far, but it is missing the ability to restrict based on 4 or more matched  numbers.

```
=QUERY(RESULTADOS!A:U;
 "SELECT * WHERE (
  C like '"&A1&"' OR D like '"&A1&"'
  OR E like '"&A1&"' OR F like '"&A1&"'
  OR G like '"&A1&"' OR H like '"&A1&"')
  OR (C like '"&B1&"' OR D like '"&B1&"'
  OR E like '"&B1&"' OR F like '"&B1&"'
  OR G like '"&B1&"' OR H like '"&B1&"')
  OR (C like '"&C1&"' OR D like '"&C1&"'
  OR E like '"&C1&"' OR F like '"&C1&"'
  OR G like '"&C1&"' OR H like '"&C1&"')
  OR (C like '"&D1&"' OR D like '"&D1&"'
  OR E like '"&D1&"' OR F like '"&D1&"'
  OR G like '"&D1&"' OR H like '"&D1&"')
  OR (C like '"&E1&"' OR D like '"&E1&"'
  OR E like '"&E1&"' OR F like '"&E1&"'
  OR G like '"&E1&"' OR H like '"&E1&"')
  OR (C like '"&F1&"' OR D like '"&F1&"'
  OR E like '"&F1&"' OR F like '"&F1&"'
  OR G like '"&F1&"' OR H like '"&F1&"')";1)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/170758/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()`, `byrow()` and `match()`, like this:

```
=filter( 
  A6:U20, 
  byrow(C6:U20, lambda(row, 
    4 <= counta(iferror(filter(row, match(row, A3:F3, 0)))) 
  )) 
)
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197), [byrow()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) and [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).

Comment: Simply splendid! it worked perfectly and the return was even faster.
Thanks!